# Find total numbers from column of string numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe df which looks like this:

```
col1      col2      col3      

 A         123      0.1     
 A         1235     0.2        
 A         1232     0.2    
 A         12       0.05       
 B         23       0.04    
 B         234      0.065    
 B         235      0.08    
 B         2368     0.3    
 B         2369     0.25    
 B         23679    0.6
```

Now from this df, I want to calculate for each group how many numbers would be included for every prefix value in col2. For example for group A I would like to have

```
col1     col2      new_col

  A        123        8
  A        1235       1
  A        1232       1
  A        12         90
  B        23         779
  B        234        100
  B        235        100
  B        2368       10
  B        2369       10
  B        23679      1
```

To give a bit more 123 would contain the following set of numbers:
(1230, 1231, 1232, 1233, 1234, 1235, 1236, 1237, 1238, 1239) but 1232 and 1235 exist in different df's rows, hence 10-2  = 8 numbers. Same for 12. It will contain all the 100 numbers between 1200 and 1299 - the 10 given numbers in the different rows, hence 90.

The logic that I followed so far is the following:
- Create a column with the col2 length.
- Find the maximum character length per group

```
   df['prefix_length'] = df['col2'].str.len()
   df['max_length'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(max)
   df['total_numbers'] = 10 ** (df['max_length'] - df['prefix_length'])
```

The dataframe is not sorted and I have many groups. In col2 all the string numbers start with the same minimum length prefix. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: on what basis are you deciding number of 0 to be appended in the group you are trying to form? and how did you come up with "the 10 given numbers in the different rows, hence 90." 23679  > 1299 so it cannot be in the group of 1200-1299.

Comment: It's decided by the maximum number of digits on eaach group. So the first group will always contain 4 digit numbers (maximum length of this group come from the values 1235 and 1232) and will always start with 12 (minimum length of this group is 12). Therefore the range of numbers that start with 12 will be the 100 numbers between 1200 and 1299. Subsequently the 123 will contain all numbers between 1230 and 1239, so 10 numbers. But there already exist in my dataframe the 1232 and 1235, so 123 will have 10-2 = 8 numbers, and the 12 prfix will contain 100 - 2 - 8 = 90 numbers.